# unsupported port number: 0

Tags: docker-compose, port, containerdctl, nerdctl

If we specify single port in dockerfile or docker-compose file like below

```
  sshd:
    build: ./backend/mock/sshd
    volumes:
      - ./docker/sftp_upload_dir:/root/upload_dir
    ports:
      - '22'. #<----------
```

and use the docker-compose file with nerdctl using command

```
nerdctl compose up
```

then nerdctl command will exit with following error

```
FATA[0000] unsupported port number: 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As per docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

```
There are three options:

Specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER)
Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port).
```

Thus 0 is chosen as the host port which creates error, so solution is to explicitly specify host port as below

```
  sshd:
    build: ./backend/mock/sshd
    volumes:
      - ./docker/sftp_upload_dir:/root/upload_dir
    ports:
      - '22:22' #<<<<---------
```

Note that I have explicitly added `22:` before `22` in the last line to make it work with `nerdctl`. It works by default with docker-compose up.

Comment: So why wouldn’t `'22'` (no period) work? In the linked documentation it shows `'3000'` This matches the rule “Specify just the container port (*an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port*).”

Comment: good comment,    I forgot to explicitly mention that I am using this with `nerdctl` command, not with `docker` .